# Python subclass factory

Tags: python, class, factory

I have a number of subclasses of a single parent class and want to instantiate them according to strings in serialized data. My approach is to map the instantiating strings to classes and then create corresponding objects using a factory method:

```
class Superclass:
    @classmethod
    def get_instance(cls, string):
        return CLASSMAP[string]()

    def name(self):
        pass

class Foo(Superclass):
    def name(self):
        return "my name is Foo"

class Bar(Superclass):
    def name(self):
        return "i'm Bar"

class Baz(Superclass):
    def name(self):
        return "i am called Baz"

CLASSMAP = {
    'foo': Foo,
    'bar': Bar,
    'baz': Baz,
}
```

I don't like having the CLASSMAP as a global dictionary, but I cannot define it as a member of Superclass right in the declaration due to the subclasses not having been defined yet (and they have to be defined after the superclass, of course). I can of course assign the class map into the class afterwards:

```
Superclass.CLASSMAP = {...}
```

and have Superclass' get_instance() method refer to the not-yet-existing field, but it seems even clunkier and prone to errors.

Is there a more Pythonic approach to the whole pattern?

Comment: `CONSTANT` dictionary seems fine to me...

Comment: there is always a good idea to *encapsulate* stuffs like `CLASSMAP` into another *raw* class and then write wrapper functions in it with *private* variables to do the job!

Comment: You could use a MetaClass which registers the subclasses in a classvariable. Here is an example which uses a set to register the subclasses. It would be simple to change that to a dict: http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Metaprogramming.html#example-self-registration-of-subclasses

Answer (score 2):

If you make your super class a new-style class inheriting from object, you can solve this dynamically, using `cls.__subclasses__()`:

```
class Superclass(object):
    @classmethod
    def get_instance(cls, string):
        return next(c for c in cls.__subclasses__() if c.__name__.lower() == string)()
```

A mixed approach combining the advantage of adding classes dynamically while still having `O(1)` class lookup:

```
class Superclass(object):
    @classmethod
    def get_instance(cls, string):
        return MAPPING[string]()

class Foo(Superclass):
    lookup = 'foo'

class Bar(Superclass):
    lookup = 'bar'

MAPPING = {c.lookup: c for c in Superclass.__subclasses__()}
```

Comment: An error message like "`SuperClass` has no `__subclasses__` member"

Comment: This is of course a possibility, but in this particular case I'd rather be explicit with the mapping and not commit myself to naming classes in a specific way and dynamically mangling the names.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Yes. Like `class Superclass(object)`.

Comment: @voland If you use the class name for serialization as well, you avoid all mangling. And if you change the name of a class, your serialized data breaks either way, unless you have an explicit backwards mapping for serialization which you need to keep in sync, as well. Pros and cons ;) I am with you on explicity.

Comment: In this instance the serialized data is provided by a third party and I only have to process the data one way, so that is not an issue. Sorry for being a bit unclear in the opening post.

Comment: Then again all classes could have the `serialized_name` as a field and the `get_instance()` method could dynamically iterate through its `__subclasses__` to find the class with the matching name. This would remove the need for a mapping dictionary altogether.

Comment: @voland Valid approach, too. Downside of the enire dynamic approach is, of course, `O(N)` lookup as compared to `O(1)` dict lookup. But with a limited number of classes that shouldn't be an issue.